# Find if a String is Contained in Delimiters in PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$string = '[Canada] [United States]';
```

I need to detect something like this

```
if($string contains Canada) {
 // Do stuff for Canada
}
```

Comment: Is it at all possible to store this data in an array, rather than a string? It is much easier to iterate through an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pull out all text between `[` and `]` and then see if it is found in the resulting array.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $string, $matches);

if (in_array('Canada', $matches[1])) {
    echo 'Hello, Canada!';
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fWn4KA).

If you just used substring searching functions, you'd run the risk that the string you searched for was the substring of a larger block between brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing simple text matching, and don't want the overhead of using the regular expressions engines, the `strpos` function may be what you are looking for.
See the PHP Manual page for [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for more details.

```
if(strpos($string,"Canada")!==FALSE){
    // Do stuff for Canada
}
```

The use of the `strpos()` function is preferred over `strstr()` due to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) stating that for instances that the programmer only cares about finding a match, not where the match is located, `strpos()` is faster and less memory intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php).

Comment: Pretty sure my response was an answer and not a comment.  For your reference, this response is a comment, however.